# Why am I getting a "Cannot GET /error" message when running my app?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I do `npm start` and visit localhost:3000/ it just says `"Cannot GET /error"`. And I have a app.get function so I am not sure why this shows up.

Here's some related code that might be helpful in figuring out I thought:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const page = Math.max(0, req.query.page);
  const wrongPassword = req.query.wrongPassword;
  Update.find().limit(perPage).skip(perPage * page).sort({ createdAt: 'desc' }).exec().then((updates) => {
    Update.count().exec().then((count) => {
      const pages = count / perPage;
      res.render('index', { title: 'Trial', updates, wrongPassword, page, pages, moment });
    }).catch(() => {
      res.redirect('/error');
    });
  }).catch(() => {
    res.redirect('/error');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your server by make it listen to a port you want, which in this case is 3000.

```
app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:3000`))
```

Comment: So I already have that in my mongoose.connect method: app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`));